# Query to check if sequence of brackets is valid

Tags: algorithm, validation, brackets

I'm trying to solve pretty complex problem with bracket sequence, only '(' and ')', actually I need to implement segment tree that in logarithmic time will check if sequence of brackets is valid or not.

Valid sequence of bracket is a string that is either:

- The empty string
- A string (B) where B is valid sequence of brackets
- LR, the concentration of two strings L and R which are both valid sequences of brackets.

Now with those conditions I need to implement segment tree that for query will check if the range [A,B] is valid sequence of brackets.

Actually what I need in my program is index K such that K <= B and the sequence [A,K] is valid sequence of brackets, K is maximum possible, but I think that I cannot implement segment tree that will give me index K, so I think that I will try to implement segment tree that will only check if the sequence is valid or not.

**Example**

sequence = "()((()))(())" query_1 = [1,2], answer for query 1 is true because the sequence "()" is valid.
query_2=[1,6]= "()((()" this sequence is not valid and the query should return false;

**What I have tried**

I implemented check with stack that checks if sequence of brackets is valid or not, but that check works in O(N) and I think that we can check this in O(logN)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can to do some pre-processing, like first find that which substring of length 2 are valid, then check which substring length 3 are valid( which will be none ) , then which sequence of length  4 are valid and so on .... till length of the string. This pre-processing will take O(n^2) time complexity and space, while query will take O(1) time complexity.

Comment: But I forgot to mention in the post that the length of the string will be up to 10^5 so we can't do pre processing in O(N^2)

Comment: Then my approach will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Make all your `(` be equal to +1, and all the `)` equal to -1. Now run through the parenthesis string and create a new array out of it by cumulatively adding the value of the bracket (+1/-1). Like so:

```
( ) ( ( ( ) ) ) ( ( ) )
1 0 1 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 1 0
```

Now if some `[i,j]` is a valid sequence, then for every `x` such that `i<=x<=j`, `[i,x]` should contain more open brackets `(` than closed brackets `)`. If `())` was a segment, it's final value would be (1)+(-1)+(-1) = -1, which is negative. This implies that the number of `)` in the segment is more than the number of `(`s. Which is impossible in a valid sequence. Similarly for a segment `())(()`, although the final sum of the segment would be zero, the sum at index three (1-indexed) would be -1. So this would be invalid.

So for any query `[i,j]` we just have to check if in *that* segment, whether there exists any point `x` such that the `sum([i,x]) <= 0`. If it is, return false. Also make a check that the number of `(` is equal to that of `)`.

For this, maintain a minimum range query segment tree of the sum array. Find the minimum value in range `[i,j]`. (Call that `val`). If `val - sum[i-1] < 0` return false. Again, make a check for `( == )`.

Comment: So more formally, you say that we should keep two values for each node, minimal value and sum, if the minimal value - sum of the query is less than 0 then the sequence is not valid. Am I right?

Comment: If `sum` is the initial cumulative sum array (prefix sum), then create the min. range segment tree out of this `sum` array. Then for any query `[i,j]`, find the minimum using the tree, and then remove `sum[i-1]` from this minimum. If this final value is less than zero, the answer is no. Also check that `sum[j] - sum[i-1] == 0`, this ensures that the open brackets are same as closed brackets in that segment.

Comment: I just tried to code up your solution, and I think that the minimal value is always going to be either -1 or 1,because the array consists only of -1 and 1s, is it changing something?

Comment: Also, let's consider this example: ( ( ) ) ( ), and query = [0, n-1] where n is the length of the string, for this query minvalue=-1 and the total sum = 0, -1 - 0 < 0 so it will be wrong, what should i change in my segment tree

Comment: For `( ( ) ) ( )`, the sum array is `1 2 1 0 1 0`. The minimum value is 0. Since the query starts from the beginning of the string, this is your final value. 0 >= 0, so the first check is true.

Comment: @someone12321 Minimum value is for the `sum` array, not the individual elements.

Comment: @four_lines: "(((" sum [1,2,3] check sequence from (2,3) in 1 index based system. Based on your logic it would return true but as you are checking '(' and ')' it will be ok but then won't the solution be O(n)? In not balanced case, the algorithm returns straight not-balanced but if it is "yes" then additional ( == ) confirmation is done, right?

Comment: @newbie_old The first check will return yes. But the second check is then done for confirming whether `(` and `)` appear equal number of times. For this to be true, `sum[3] - sum[2-1]` should be 0. This can be done in O(1), since `sum` has been precomputed. Yes, if the first check passes, the `==` check is also done.